# cause of everything?

Tags: logic, causality

Ornaments (gold ornaments) cannot be made without gold. Ornaments are nothing but gold.

1. The cause of everything is included in everything.
2. If the cause of everything is A, then A is included in everything.
3. The cause of A is A.

Comment: Is there a question? If it is whether the argument is valid, then yes, more or less, if A is the cause of everything then it is, in particular, its own cause. However, nothing in this argument entails that A exists, so the conclusion should be "if A is the cause of everything then the cause of A is A".

Comment: What is the argument supporting first premise?

Answer (score 0):

**Every cause itself becomes an effect and an effect is the cause in a changed form.** We cannot remove the cause from the effect.  That means it is the cause in a changed form.

And if you explore the cause of causes you will reach an uncaused cause.  The Supreme Self being an uncaused cause for all that has been created, has no beginning.

Please read about the relation between [cause and effect](http://www.indiapost.com/the-effect-is-nothing-but-the-cause-in-different-form/).

If you wish to use the words more precisely you may change the word 'included'.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is caused.

- The first event ever (a.k.a. Big Bang) was not caused.
- Non-physical mental phenomena are not caused.

So there is not any cause of everything.

Comment: _Big Bang was not caused_ Citation needed. _mental phenomena are not caused_ Neuroscience begs to differ.

Comment: Nothing happened before the Big Bang. There could not possible have been any prior event to cause it. Mental phenomena are not physical events, only physical events are caused. Neuroscience is not psychology.

Comment: _There could not possible have been any prior event to cause it._ What makes you so sure? _Mental phenomena are not physical events_ Citation needed. _Neuroscience is not psychology._ Agree. They are different approaches to understand same reality.

Comment: Pure logic says: Before the first event ever there was nothing. Mental phenomena have no measurable physical properties. No citation needed. Neuroscience and psychology study different things. The former studies physical phenomena in the brain. The latter studies mental phenomena.

Comment: It presupposes there is a "first event". "Beings" of a digital world will have their own conception of Bigbang although the cause (humans) exist. _Mental phenomena have no measurable physical properties._ It is becoming increasingly less and less true. "Conciousness" is the only major remaining nut to crack.

Answer (score 0):

'The cause of everything is included in everything."

Unless the cause is God.

"If the cause of everything is A, then A is included in everything."

Not if A is God

"The cause of A is A."

If A is God, yes. If A is the universe, no, because God is the cause.

Comment: "god" is part of "everything"

Comment: @tejasvi88 Then there is no cause of everything.  If everything is the universe only then there always is a cause. Even for the eternal everything (god).  Everything happens because of gods. The gods have no cause. The eternal everything is caused by gods.